# Android dialog with TextView As link

Tags: java, android

Hi guys I have a problem regarding the android dialog box.What I am trying to do is set few lines of description in a dialog box which I am able to do it fine but at last i need a link called "see more" which will redirect the user to other activity.I am very new to android and these is the first of some things what I am trying to do any help will be appreciated..my code onStart()

```
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    /*final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);
    dialog.setTitle("About Service One");


    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button12);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  
            dialog.dismiss();            
        }  
    });

    dialog.show();
```

Comment: create custom dialog... [http://androidexample.com/Custom_Dialog_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=88&aaid=111]

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: @Booyaches On strat of an activity i need to display an dialog with few description about the app and provide a link "see more" that should redirect to other activity where i will be breifly descibing about the app

Comment: create a custom dialog and create a button on it as show more... start new Activity on button click .

Comment: @sourabhbans i want to make it has link not button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void onStart()
    {
    super.onStart();

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.main);
dialog.setTitle("About Service One");


Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button12);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View view) {  
        dialog.dismiss();            
    }  
});
TextView showMore= (TextView ) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tvShowMore);
showMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
    @Override  
    public void onClick(View view) {  
Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowMoreActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);       
         }  
    });
dialog.show();

 }


And add in xml showmore TextView Which set text from string.xml 
i.e  <string name="show_more"><u>Show More </u></string> use this for set linkable text
```

main.xml

...........

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvShowMore"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/show_more"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
   >
</TextView>
```

............

Comment: I want to make it has link not button

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom Dialod layout>> create a text view as show more >> set OnClick Listener on it as ..

You can set the click handler in xml with these attribute:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

Don't forget the clickable attribute, without it, the click handler isn't called.

dailog.xml

```
...

<TextView 
   android:id="@+id/click"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
   android:text="show more"
   android:textSize="55sp"
   android:onClick="onClick"                
   android:clickable="true"/>
...
```

MyActivity.java

```
   public class MyActivity extends Activity {

      public void onClick(View v) {
       // ... start show more activity here
      }  
   }
```

OR... find the view  using dialog and set OnClick Listener on it..

```
showmore = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.click);
showmore..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 // ... start show more activity here
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/yourId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
android:text="Show more"
android:onClick="showMore"                
android:clickable="true"/>
```

Inside your activity, get that textView :

```
TextView showMoreView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourId);
```

Add this showMoreView inside your text in the dialog and
Inside your activity, define the methode "showMore"

```
public void showMore(View view)
{
Intent intent =new Intent(YourCurrrentActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
```

This will take you to NextActivity on clicking the "show more" text.